# How to send GA4 events to google analytics using measurement protocol in Laravel App

Tags: laravel, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have this code in my `laravel` app that sends UA events to google analytics:

```php
Http::asForm()->post('https://www.google-analytics.com/collect', [
    'v' => '1',
    'tid' => config('services.google.analytics.tids.ua.all'),
    'cid' => (string) $cid,
    't' => 'event',
    'ec' => $category,
    'ea' => $action,
    'el' => $label,
    'ev' => $value,
]);
```

I need to achieve the same, but to send it to GA4 and I can't seem to find any details on it in their documentation. Anyone had this resolved?

Comment: [Measurement protocol for ga4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4) its very limited you may not be able to do what you want

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo thank you for your comment. I am wondering why do they announcing shut down of UA if GA4 is not capable of doing what UA was doing. Do you have any suggestions on how to approach this particular issue? Basically I just need a way to send custom defined events to GA4 from the backend. 

Thank you very much!

Comment: My suggestion is that you accept that GA4 is not the same as UA and that you are not going to be able to do what you could with the old UA version when UA is shut down.    I cant comment as to why Google decided not to enable the same features in GA4 that they had in UA I have been asking that question since they first invited me to alpha test GA4